# If a SQL Server Database is read only can I grant a single user write access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, readonly, user-permissions

I have a SQL Server database that we are trying to make read-only for everyone except one user. I already went to properties>options>Database read-only = true and set the entire DB to read-only. Now we are finding that one program updates this DB and will not work correctly without being able to do so. Is there a way to leave the whole DB read-only and just grant write to this one single "user"? SQL server 2008 using SSMS 2017.

Comment: Nope. You can't have it be both readonly and not readonly at the same time. You could have one role that is datawriter and have that app use that role and all other roles be datareader.

Comment: This seems a DBA question and the stack DBA site is probably a better place for this.  Voting to migrate

Comment: why cant use roles and permissions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a database that is read-only cannot be written to by any user. You're best solution would be to give read only permissions to all users except this app.